# Categorical assignments using pd.apply based on multiple conditions on Pandas Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains Item Id numbers with multiple tasks and completion dates for those tasks. I am trying to assign categories based on task completions or in-completions in a separate column

my data frame looks like this:

```
Item ID     Task 1 Comp Date  Task 2 Comp Date  Task 3 Comp Date
12781463    NaT               NaT               NaT
10547725    6/6/2019          7/30/2019         8/1/2019
12847251    5/31/2019         6/12/2019         NaT
12734403    5/31/2019         NaT               NAT
```

to test my approach to my challenge i took a subset of my data set and wrote a portion of the function that will be used with pd.apply(). below is some sample code for my .apply() function

```
def gating(row):
    if row['Task 1 Comp Date'].isnull():
        return "Pending Task 1"
    if row['Task 3 Comp Date'] .notnull():
        return "Complete"


df['Gating'] = df.apply(gating, axis = 1)
```

i was expecting to see a value of "Complete" for Item ID10547725 but got

AttributeError: ("'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'notnull'", 'occurred at index 8')

Is there a different approach i should take?

Comment: Change `row['Task 1 Comp Date'].isnull()` for `pd.isnull(row['Task 1 Comp Date'])`

Comment: that part worked however i need to be able to use conditional & for another check and it densest seem to play nice with the .apply

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a different approach i should take?

Rafaelc offered the correct answer:

> Change `row['Task 1 Comp Date'].isnull()` for `pd.isnull(row['Task 1 Comp Date'])`

This remedies the "Trouble With NaNs" diagnostic you reported:

> AttributeError: ("'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'notnull'", 'occurred at index 8')

The current question that you asked has been answered.
Your "use conditional & for another check" remark suggests
that perhaps you would like to post a separate question.

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem. If you read one of my test cases above

Answer (score 0):

2 years after this question had been asked, I encountered a similar error. I solved it according to [the solution of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501214/issue-checking-for-missing-datetime-value-in-series), by checking if it was `pd.NaT` instead of using `isnull()` or `notnull()`

Here is how to change the op's example.

```py
def gating(row):
    if row['Task 1 Comp Date'] is pd.NaT:
        return "Pending Task 1"
    if row['Task 3 Comp Date'] is not pd.NaT:
        return "Complete"
```