# Unable to test for NaT in Pandas dataframe using a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a function to compare a set of dates in each row of a dataframe after checking for NaT values in one of the columns. I get a "'Timestamp' object has no attribute"   error on the isnull test.

```
import pandas as pd

a =['2018-01-01','2019-01-01','2020-01-01']
b =['2018-12-31','2019-12-31', 'NaT']

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":a,"b":b})
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

#if date value in col b is later than col a return col b
def datefix(x):
    if x['b'].isnull() == True:
        result = x['a']

    elif x['b']> x['a']:
        result = x['b']
    return result

#isnull test in function fails with error 
df['c']=df.apply(datefix,axis=1)
```

What confuses me is when I use isnull over the same column in the dataframe direclty without a function the test works fine:

```
    #isnull test works over dataframe
    b = df[df['b'].isnull() == True]
    print(b)

           a   b
2 2020-01-01 NaT
```

Comment: Try without the True.. `if x['b'].isnull():`

Comment: Nope. Same error. But thanks.

Comment: How about is if `x['b'] is pd.NaT:`

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: Thanks XXavier,  `x['b'] is pd.NaT:`  works.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer here [Issue checking for missing datetime value in series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501214/issue-checking-for-missing-datetime-value-in-series) :

Use `is pd.NaT` instead of `.isnull()`

Comment: This is the same as my answer in the comment right?

Comment: Yes, thanks XXavier. Sorry I found myself before I saw you second comment

Answer (score 1):

Just to complemente the right answers, in python comparing to `None`, `False`, and `True` can not be done with `==` operator, but with `is` operator:

```
a = True
a == True # False
a is True # True
```

The same applies for np.nan and pd.NaT

```
a = pd.NaT
a == pd.NaT # False
a is pd.NaT # True
```

Comment: Thanks jcaliz. That's helpful to know.